# How to use DISTINCT key word with ORDER BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a table With values

```
 ID  Number
 1    6
 2    6
 3    7
 4    7
 5    1
 6    1
 7    2
 8    2
```

I wrote a select query for distinct Numbers

```
SELECT DISTINCT Number FROM Table
```

I got output like

```
 ID  Number
 1    1
 2    2
 3    6
 4    7
```

But I want output like

```
ID  Number
 1    6
 2    7
 3    1
 4    2
```

How can I bring output like this??

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT Number FROM Table` will only return a single column, however you state that you got an output with two columns. So either your SQL is wrong or your sample output is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use windowed function like `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT Number, MAX(ID) AS max_ID
  FROM #Tab
  GROUP BY Number
)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY max_ID) AS ID, Number
FROM cte
ORDER BY max_ID
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/404683)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔════╦════════╗
║ ID ║ Number ║
╠════╬════════╣
║  1 ║      6 ║
║  2 ║      7 ║
║  3 ║      1 ║
║  4 ║      2 ║
╚════╩════════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to remove duplicate `Numbers` and preserve the ordering by `ID`.

One possible way is to use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
DECLARE @T TABLE ([ID] int, [Number] int);

INSERT INTO @T ([ID], [Number]) VALUES
    (1, 6),
    (2, 6),
    (3, 7),
    (4, 7),
    (5, 1),
    (6, 1),
    (7, 2),
    (8, 2);

WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        ID
        ,Number
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Number ORDER BY ID) AS rn
    FROM @T AS T
)
SELECT
    ID
    ,Number
FROM CTE
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY ID;
```

**Result**

```
ID  Number
1   6
3   7
5   1
7   2
```